# What does cv::Mat's deallocate method do?

Tags: c++, opencv, reference-counting, opencv-mat

The following code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  cv::Mat1b i1(cv::Size(1, 2));
  i1.at<uchar>(0, 0) = 1;
  i1.at<uchar>(1, 0) = 1;

  cv::Mat1b mask(i1.size());
  mask.at<uchar>(0, 0) = 1;
  mask.at<uchar>(1, 0) = 0;

  cv::Mat1b masked;
  mask.copyTo(masked, mask);

  masked.release(); //or .deallocate()
  cout << masked << endl;
  i1.copyTo(masked, 1 - mask);
  cout << masked << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

behaves very differently when `masked.release()` is replaced by `masked.deallocate()`. In the latter case it seems that the matrix `masked` is not modified at all and the output `masked` is the sum of masked and invert masked matrices, thus equal to the original `im1` matrix. What does `deallocate()` member method actually do? I use openCV 3.1.

Comment: [Mat::release](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae48d4913285518e2c21a3457017e716e). By using the object after calling `deallocate()` you're likely experiencing undefined behavior.

Comment: I would think that `release()` and `deallocate()` do the same thing. And both should leave the object in a "clear" state.

Comment: Except the documentation clearly states that `release()` and `deallocate()` do not do the same thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deallocate()` will deallocate the data directly form the `cv::Mat`. However, `release()` will just decrease the `ref_count` of the `cv::Mat` and if it hits 0, it will call `deallcoate` by itself.

**Summary:** use `release` always until you know what you are doing.

Be aware also that you do not need to invoke any of them. `release` will be invoked during the destructor of `cv::Mat`.

P.S using the data of `cv::Mat` after deallocating is considered undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

While `Mat::deallocate()` deallocates the matrix, `Mat::release()` decreases the reference counter and deallocates the matrix **if needed**. When using release() if reference count reaches 0, Mat is then deallocated, while deallocate() deallocates it always. More information [HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae48d4913285518e2c21a3457017e716e)